# To pass parameters with Tabhost

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost

How to pass parameters between tabhost
I have this ActivityMain code.
And I would like to pass the passwords from imbox, to outbox
Thank you

Comment: Can you show us your code, or give us more information about what you want to do please?

Comment: create interface

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I do not know why not let me put the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

            // Inbox Tab
            TabSpec inboxSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(INBOX_SPEC);
            // Tab Icon
            inboxSpec.setIndicator(INBOX_SPEC, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.huevo));

            Intent inboxIntent = new Intent(this, InboxActivity.class);

            startActivity(inboxIntent);
            // Tab Content
            inboxSpec.setContent(inboxIntent);

            // Outbox Tab
            TabSpec outboxSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(OUTBOX_SPEC);
            outboxSpec.setIndicator(OUTBOX_SPEC, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.huevodos));
            Intent outboxIntent = new Intent(this, OutboxActivity.class);
            outboxSpec.setContent(outboxIntent);

            // Profile Tab
            TabSpec profileSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(PROFILE_SPEC);
            profileSpec.setIndicator(PROFILE_SPEC, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.lock));
            Intent profileIntent = new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class);
            profileSpec.setContent(profileIntent);

            // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
            tabHost.addTab(inboxSpec); // Adding Inbox tab
            tabHost.addTab(outboxSpec); // Adding Outbox tab
            tabHost.addTab(profileSpec); // Adding Profile tab
    }
```

}

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class InboxActivity extends ListActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.inbox_list);

    }
}
```